# Using standalone.sh but cant see welcome page or web mgmt interface

Tags: java, jboss

I downloaded and extracted JBOSS AS 7.1.1. I executed the Standalone.sh script also.
However, now when I try to go to

```
 http:// IP-address:8080
```

or

```
  http:// IP-address:9990/console
```

I get an error that Google Chrome cannot display the web page.

In the console(Putty) I can see that JBOSS has started successfully. Why am I unable to see the welcome page/admin interface?

UPDATE- Output of command

```
netstat -tulpen
```

is given below--

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State           User       Inode      PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      27         428559475  31847/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          428559730  7714/httpd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          428554917  31428/perl
tcp        0      0 89.22.97.219:53             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      25         428559819  32162/named
tcp        0      0 89.22.97.215:53             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      25         428559817  32162/named
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      25         428559815  32162/named
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      99         428559363  31674/proftpd: (acc
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          428518498  24097/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11000             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          428566351  6633/lookup-domain-
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      26         428559680  32048/postmaster
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      25         428559820  32162/named
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          428555252  31610/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          428559732  7714/httpd
udp        0      0 89.22.97.219:53             0.0.0.0:*                               25         428559818  32162/named
udp        0      0 89.22.97.215:53             0.0.0.0:*                               25         428559816  32162/named
udp        0      0 127.11.107.1:53             0.0.0.0:*                               25         428559814  32162/named
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000               0.0.0.0:*                               0          428554918  31428/perl
```

Comment: Can you update your post with results for the following commands: `iptables -L -v -n` and `netstat -tulpen`?

Comment: @BartDeVos for the first command(iptables) I am getting this output--  can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied (you must be root) Is there something I am doing wrong here? I have logged in as root user and I am executing the command as root... Thanks...

Comment: Are you on an OpenVZ VPS? Then, this is to be expected.

Comment: @BartDeVos - yes I am on an OpenVZ VPS...

Answer (score 2):

No process is listening on `8080` or `9990`, so your service isn't running. What is the command you ran to start the server? Do you have a configuration file?

Since you are using an OpenVZ-VPS, there might be an issue with your java. Take a look at this:
http://davidanand.blogspot.com/2010/06/jboss-tomcat-on-openvz-centos.html

Comment: I used the following command to start the server: nohup /usr/java/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/standalone.sh &, i have created a file at /etc/init.d/jboss-which behaves like a jboss startup/shutdown script...the above command is part of that file...

Comment: Try running `/usr/java/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/standalone.sh` (without the `&`) and see if any errors pop up.

Comment: @BartDeVos- I ran "sh /usr/java/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/standalone.sh" and it shows that JBOSS has started successfully...however I still cant access the console or web interface...